# WKWebView content stretch in iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

[image: iOS 14 Barcode stretch issue]
[image: iOS 13 Barcode displays proper]

When I hit one specific URL into WKWEbView , Barcode get stretch in iOS 14 , Barcode displays proper in iOS 13.

Can anyone help me on this problem?